# Measuring time taken to fetch DB data in Data service

Tags: wcf, dataservice

Is there any way to measure the time taken for data from Database using WCF Data service. So that we can log it for our analysis purpose?

Any pointers or suggestions on this will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to mark the stop and end of the call to the database, and then log the result?

Comment: Hi... I would like to find the time it takes when we request for some exposed entities in wCF data service... Since the svc file directly uses the db context to expose the entities.... This entities is being auto generated... we cant put our stop watch related code in it.... Is there any way to measure the time take to fetch data for each entities...

Comment: any pointers or suggestions