# Measuring db access time in data service

Tags: wcf, dataservice

Is there any way for us to measure the time taken by the WCF data service to fetch entities from Database.

For eg. Lets say that we expose the NortherWind DB through data-service and accessed Orders entities through below URL,

```
http://<domain>/Dataservice/Orders
```

Any ways to measure the time taken to fetch Orders table contents from DB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21085658/745969).  At the very least add more context to your question (preferably the original one) so you won't get answers like matcheek's below that aren't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was made exactly for that purpose